# Read every line from a file and save its content in a char[] array

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, ifstream

My assignment involves reading the first 150 characters of each line of a file (or if the line is shorter than 150 characters, until the end of the line) and searching for a specific letter in that line. The problem is that I cannot use the standart function `getline()` from the
`<fstream>`
library because its argument is a string and using strings in the assignment is forbidden. After several tries the code that did the task as close as possible was

```
fstream myFile;
myFile.open("message.txt", fstream::in);
char buffer[150];
for (buffer; myFile.getline(&buffer[0], MAX_LENGTH, '\n'); )     //MAX_LENGTH=150
{         
     getLetter(buffer);
}
myFile.close();
```

The code doesn't work because when it encounters a line that is more than 150 characters, it skips it (while it should take the first 150 characters and ignore the rest). How can I solve the problem?

Comment: _"when it encounters a line that is more than 150 characters, it skips it"_ - What does that mean? What happens?

Comment: Instead of the getLetter() function, I had a `cout<<buffer; `. When I ran the code, that line (which was 150 "a"s) was simply ommited, not printed. What is more, when I edited that line in the text file so that it was less than 150 characters long, some of them were changed from "a"s to "p"s

Comment: Remember, `char[150]` can hold **149 characters** as you must have a NUL terminator.

Comment: I'd gladly use string but I am not allowed to. This is part of a homework assignment

Comment: "Using strings is forbidden" is, unfortunately, a sign that this is one of *those* C++ courses that's functionally useless and effectively fails to teach actual C++. I hope you can survive this without too much damage!

Comment: Since you're using what amounts to "fancy C" then be absolutely sure you're calculating your buffer sizes correctly. You need `MAX_LENGTH + 1`.

Comment: One thing to note is your `for` is actually just a `while`. Use the correct tool for the job here. `for (buffer; ...)` doesn't really make any sense. `while (myFile.getline(...))` is the right way to express the same thing.

Comment: @tadman I am actually stidying Software Engineering at the oldest and "the best" university in my country. But yes, I totally agree with you. In fact, I am studying more Maths than programming which is hillarious and pointless!

Comment: I guess I'll have to write a function that does the job myself.

Comment: If your course is only ten years out of date then you're at a fantastic school. Lesser programs have their material more than thirty years out of date.